# サイトコレクション作成時にエラーが出ます

Tags: sharepoint

Microsoft SharePoint において、サイトコレクション作成の際、以下のエラーが発生して失敗してしまいます。

> 申し訳ございません。何らかの問題が発生しました。
>   Feature with Id {ID} is not installed in this farm, and cannot be added to this scope.

テンプレートは【ブログ】を選択しており、
サイトコレクションの管理者、及び代理管理者には同一のAdministratorsグループ所属ユーザを設定しました。
サイトで使用するポートは解放済みです。

情報をお持ちの方いらっしゃいましたら頂きたく存じます。

Comment: [タグ付けのガイドライン](/help/tagging)に沿って、タイトルからタグ欄にタグ情報を移しました。新しくタグを作るには信用度がある程度必要になるので、タグが必要になったら[meta]でリクエストしてください。また、投稿にはMarkdown記法で簡単に引用文などが書けます。[ヘルプセンターのまとめ](/editing-help)が参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: [こちら](http://blog.krichie.com/2011/09/02/programmatically-waiting-on-sharepoint-solutions-to-deploy/)を見てください。コードサンプルもあります。（英語）

Comment: @ento 
ご指摘ありがとうございます。
次回投稿時やコメント時のために熟読します。

Comment: @JorgeBucaran
SharePointの機能としてサイト作成機能があるものと考えていましたが、コード記述による環境の編集が必要なのでしょうか？回答の受付を継続しつつ調査も進めることにします。